# wordpress nav class id bug wp menu

Tags: php, wordpress, class, content-management-system, nav

Hi all wordpress refuses to add the id and class specified in the array, it ignores the code, If i inspect element i get a bunch of WordPress classes instead. Can anyone help?

(the location registering works fine)

```
<div class="menu-main-nav-container">
<ul id="menu-main-nav" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-110">
```

// found in functions.php

```
function html5blank_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => 'header-menu',
        'container'       => 'false',
        'container_class' => 'testclass',
        'container_id'    => 'testid',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => '',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}



    function register_html5_menu()
    {
        register_nav_menus(array( // Using array to specify more menus if needed
            'header-menu' => __('header-menu', 'html5blank'), // Main Navigation
        ));
    }

    add_action('init', 'register_html5_menu'); // Add HTML5 Blank Menu
```

**code in header.php** (just a snippet)

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

            <?php html5blank_nav();?>  // call to NAV


    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to call the menu? Likely in the header.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
```

and you should put classes in `menu_class` and IDs in `menu_id` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have container set to false so the classes you have given have nowhere to go.

Change container to true if you want the classes on the container or specify class for the menu_class or menu_id.